# Grails Unit testing a function with session object

Tags: unit-testing, session, grails

I having a Controller like

```
def testFunction(testCommand cmdObj) {
    if (cmdObj.hasErrors()) {
        render(view: "testView", model: [cmdObj:cmdObj])
        return
    } else {
        try {
            testService.testFunction(cmdObj.var1, cmdObj.var2, session.user.username as String)
            flash.message = message(code: 'message')
            redirect url: createLink(mapping: 'namedUrl')
        } catch (GeneralException error) {
            render(view: "testView", model: [cmdObj:cmdObj])
            return
        }
    }
}
```

For the above controller function I having a Unit test function like:

```
def "test function" () {
        controller.session.user.username = "testUser"
        def testCommandOj = new testCommand(
                var1:var1,
                var2:var2,
                var3:var3,
                var4:var4
        )
        testService service = Mock(testService)
        controller.testService = service
        service.testFunction(var2,var3,var4)

    when: 
        controller.testFunction(testCommandOj)

    then: 
        view == "testView"
        assertTrue model.cmdObj.hasErrors()

    where:
        var1            | var2      | var3      | var4
        "testuser"      |  "word@3" | "word@4"  | "word@4"

}
```

When running this test function I getting the error like `Cannot set property 'username' on null object`, means I couldn't able to set up the session object. Can someone help to fix this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing the Grails controller's unit test, you can directly assign the variables into the session object as you do for params this way in your setup: block. I recommend you to just assign the User object in session first and then it will be fine: I have slightly modified your code:

```
def "test function" () {

setup:

    User user = new User(username:'requiredUserName').save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
    session.user = user
    def testCommandOj = new testCommand(
            var1:var1,
            var2:var2,
            var3:var3,
            var4:var4
    )
    testService service = Mock(testService)
    controller.testService = service
    service.testFunction(var2,var3,var4)

when: 
    controller.testFunction(testCommandOj)

then: 
    view == "testView"
    assertTrue model.cmdObj.hasErrors()

where:
    var1            | var2      | var3      | var4
    "testuser"      |  "word@3" | "word@4"  | "word@4"
```

}

This should be working fine now.The only problem was you did not assign the User object in session.